# Change the format of date stored in MongoDB to display on the front end

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, ejs

So I have posts section on my site where users can post to the front page, I want to display on the page the date that each post was added. I have added a notice created line to my Schema below.

**Post Schema**

```
const noticeSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
noticeTitle: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
noticeText: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
author: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'User'
},
noticeCreated: {
      type: Date, default: Date.now,
}
}, {timestamps: true 
}
);
```

I am then displaying the noticeCreated date on the front end with EJS

**Displaying with EJS**

```
<%= notices.noticeCreated %>
```

The problem is its displaying like this

**Fri Mar 04 2022 14:51:10 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)**

I Want it to display like this

**04/03/2022**

I must of spent 5+ hours trying to find a method to fix this but I can't find anything that's actually helped me. Obviously its just displaying how its stored in the mongoDB database, but is there a way i can change this?

**Stored in the database like this**

```
 noticeCreated: 2022-03-04T14:51:10.927Z,
```

Also here is my route if that helps.

```
router.get('/:id', isLoggedIn, wrapAsync (async (req, res, next) => {
const { id } = req.params;
const notices = await Notice.findById(id).populate('author');
console.log(notices)
if (!notices) {
req.flash('error', 'This Notice Does Not Exist')
res.redirect('/notice')   
}
res.render('notices/show', { notices })
}))
```

Comment: A `Date` itself does not have any format. It is in the responsibility of the front end application to format the Date output, nothing you would set in the Mongo database.

Comment: "How do I format a date?" is a super classic question. For what it's worth, I've made a [little playground](https://codepen.io/jeremythille/pen/QWqpKGj) using the native Intl object.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="card-subtitle text-muted mb-2">
            <%= article.createdAt.toLocaleDateString() %>
  </div>
```

I use this in my frontend to store date as you mention. [See Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e7vAT.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by the following  example

```
var test= "1993-06-15T00:00:00.000+00:00"

alert( new Date(test).toLocaleDateString())
```